# Suggestion for discovering inherent patterns in data

Tags: clustering, data-mining, unsupervised-learning, supervised-learning

I have a a big data set of clients with all sorts of variables that describe their background, payment history, and more...

I also have a subset of those client who all have portrayed similar idiosyncratic, yet worrisome behavior.

I want to be able to predict clients that will exhibit similar behavior or at least understand which variables contribute the most to this behavior, but I am not sure which methods I can use to learn to understand better this type of behavior.

(I tried growing a regression tree in order to discover which variables played a big role in this type of behavior but my mean-squared error was too high for it to be reliable.)

Do people have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can turn this into a binary classification problem (worrisome behaviour vs non-worrisome behaviour). For such problems you can use a plethora of methods (logistic regression, SVM, neural networks, random forest, decision tree, ...).

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to be a bit more specific -

1. how many useful variables do you have
2. how many data points do you
   have,
3. how are you classifying worrysome:  why use MSE for what
   sounds like a classification problem.
4. what proportion of the clients
   exhibit worrisome behaviour ( 10%, 1% , ...).

A few things you might consider is *class weighting* ( to make your worrysome behaviour more common), otherwise good classification can be achieved by just  predicting 'not worrysome'.

you might search for *anomaly detection* - (rather than trying to discriminate between worrysome and non worrysome you try to model 'non-worrysome'.

lastly you should look at business intelligence *data visualisation* tools - eg Tableau, Excel Power Pivot/Power View ( which allow you to visually explore different subcategorisations of the data) - these are aimed at the categorical data that is frequently useful for marketing/customer analysis ( eg child/ teenager/twentysomething/ retired, salary ... ).